# How to reference the current chunk label in knitr?

Tags: r, knitr

I want to get the current chunk label inside a chunk. Is this possible?

````
```{r my_chunk}
gettextf("This chunk is called %s", some_function_to_get_chunk_label())
```
````

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `opts_current$get` eg...

`opts_current$get(name = 'label')`

eg

````
cat(knit(text ="
```{r   'hello'}
render_markdown(strict=TRUE)
opts_current$get(name = 'label')
```
"))
````

Which gives

```
render_markdown(strict = TRUE)
opts_current$get(name = "label")

## [1] "hello"
```

Comment: Is there a way to automatically include this in every chunk? i.e. so that each chunk prints its own label as a comment?